# Determining adjacent wall using Revit API

Tags: revit-api, revit, revit-2015

I have couple of walls in a project. I want to find out which walls are adjacent to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the adjacent walls all meet at their respective endpoints, the `LocationCurve.ElementsAtJoin` property will give you exactly what you are asking for.

Unfortunately, it will not help in the case where the adjacent walls intersect each another in non-endpoints, e.g., at their midpoints or somewhere else along their location curves except the endpoints.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I tried LocationCurve.get_ElementsAtJoin(0) and it worked for me.